# Need help modify forest plot R codes

Tags: r, r-forestplot

Trying to make forest plot in R. But mine doesn't show the whisk, as is often seen in forest plot examples.
Also I'd like to get rid of the blue diamond at the bottom of the plot. Please make suggestion to code. The code runs but not producing desirable result.

Here's my R code below

```
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, 1.16, 1.18, 1.22, 1.24, 1.19, 1.17, 1.14, 1.28, NA), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, 1.14, 1.17, 1.20, 1.22, 1.18, 1.15, 1.13, 1.27, NA),
    upper = c(NA, NA, 1.16, 1.19, 1.23, 1.26, 1.21, 1.19, 1.15, 1.29, NA)),
    .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
  c("", "Disaster", "Frances", "Ivan", 
    "Katrina", "Wilma", "Rita", "Ike", 
    "Irene", "Sandy", ""),
  c("Hospitalization", "Exposure", "52,601", "74,511", 
    "20,966", "22,150", "20,964", "19,472", 
    "47,116", "58,963", NA),
  c("Hospitalization", "Non-exposure", "525,228", "730,144", 
    "197,795", "207,937", "203,007", "192,782", 
    "474,373", "541,190", NA),
  c("", "IRR", "1.16", "1.18", 
    "1.22", "1.24", "1.19", "1.17", 
    "1.14", "1.28", NA))

forestplot(tabletext, 
           cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
           is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
           clip=c(0.9,2.5), 
           xlog=TRUE, 
           col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```

Result is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjIFu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your original plot did show the whisks. Because you made x axis too big to see them. I removed `clip=c(0.9,2.5)`.

```
library(forestplot)
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, 1.16, 1.18, 1.22, 1.24, 1.19, 1.17, 1.14, 1.28, NA), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, 1.14, 1.17, 1.20, 1.22, 1.18, 1.15, 1.13, 1.27, NA),
    upper = c(NA, NA, 1.16, 1.19, 1.23, 1.26, 1.21, 1.19, 1.15, 1.29, NA)),
    .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
  c("", "Disaster", "Frances", "Ivan", 
    "Katrina", "Wilma", "Rita", "Ike", 
    "Irene", "Sandy", ""),
  c("Hospitalization", "Exposure", "52,601", "74,511", 
    "20,966", "22,150", "20,964", "19,472", 
    "47,116", "58,963", NA),
  c("Hospitalization", "Non-exposure", "525,228", "730,144", 
    "197,795", "207,937", "203,007", "192,782", 
    "474,373", "541,190", NA),
  c("", "IRR", "1.16", "1.18", 
    "1.22", "1.24", "1.19", "1.17", 
    "1.14", "1.28", NA))

forestplot(tabletext, 
       cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
       is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
     #  clip=c(0.9,2.5), # not working
       xlog=TRUE, 
       col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before drawing the forest plot, you should open a window with an adequate width.
If you are on a Windows machine, try for example:

```
windows(12,5)
p <- forestplot(tabletext, 
                cochrane_from_rmeta, new_page=TRUE,
                is.summary=c(TRUE, TRUE, rep(FALSE,8), TRUE),
                xlog=T, col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```

[image]